# HOw do i retrive the value from django model with foreign key constrain?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have two models one is

```
class NewsLikes(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
userId = models.ForeignKey(Users, db_column='userId', max_length=11, help_text="")
newsId = models.ForeignKey(NewsMappings, db_column='newsMappingId', max_length=11, help_text="")
createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="
```

and the other model is

```
class NewsMappings(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    newsId = models.ForeignKey(News, db_column='newsId', max_length=11, help_text="") 
    boardId = models.ForeignKey(Boards, db_column='boardId', max_length=11, help_text="") 
    isWallPost = models.BooleanField(db_column="isWallPost", default=False, help_text="")
```

the model news like contains foreign key of news mapping. I am passing news mapping as a context in my django templates and i want to count how many news likes id are present with respect to news mapping and display it on the templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a django documentation for [Many to one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)
which has relationship mapping between foreign key explained. In your case if you are looking for getting the list of all NewsMappings for each NewsLikeID Then check something like below

```
NewsLikes.objects.filter(NewsMapping__newsId='SomeNewsID')
```